# How to filter a Table type column by values of an adjacent column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to filter the content of each row of a Table column using values from other columns of the same row of the main table.

I have a table like this, with a Table type column:

[image]

Specifically, I want to use the values of `FirstLogin` to filter the content of the `AddIndex` tables,  using the column `SessionStart`.

I thought using `Table.SelectRows` but it seems that it doesn't differentiate well columns of the *main* table from the *embedded table*.

```
Table.SelectRows([AddIndex], each [SessionStart] > _[FirstLogin])
```

[image]

I would appreciate any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table look like this

| Id | FirstLogin | AddIndex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | [Table] |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | [Table] |

I have created this calculation. `Source` is the table above.

```
let
    Source = 
    Table.FromRecords(
        {
        [Id = 1 , FirstLogin = #date(2020,01,01),AddIndex = Table.FromRecords({[SessionId = 1, SessionStart = #date(2020,01,01)],[SessionId = 2, SessionStart = #date(2020,02,01)]})], 
        [Id = 2 , FirstLogin = #date(2020,01,01),AddIndex = Table.FromRecords({[SessionId = 1, SessionStart = #date(2020,01,01)],[SessionId = 2, SessionStart = #date(2020,02,01)]})]
        }
        ),

    Step2 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "AddIndexFiltered", (row) => Table.SelectRows(row[AddIndex],each [SessionStart] = row[FirstLogin])),
    #"Expanded AddIndexFiltered" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Step2, "AddIndexFiltered", {"SessionId", "SessionStart"}, {"SessionId", "SessionStart"})
in
    #"Expanded AddIndexFiltered"
```

### Output

| Id | FirstLogin | AddIndex | SessionId | SessionStart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | [Table] | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | [Table] | 1 | 01/01/2020 |

Comment: Thanks for your help, Angelo, it works perfectly! Where could I learn more about these 'functions parameters': (row) =>.

Comment: `(row) `is a placeholder, it could be anything. Here are more in depth description of `each` https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/01/09/each-keyword-power-query/
And here is where I got the idea of `(row)` https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/12/08/4270/power-query-m-primer-part3-functions-function-values-passing-returning-defining-inline-recursion

Answer (score 0):

You may use following approach:

```
filter = Table.ReplaceValue(YourLastStep, each [FirstLogin], 0,(a,b,c)=>
                            Table.SelectRows(a, each [SessionStart] > b),{"AddIndex"})
```